# Составить в Laravel запрос на eloquent по трем связанным моделям

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Несколько компаний делают ставки в тендере, каждая ставит несколько раз. Затем в тендере назначается выигравшая ставка.

Задача: найти все тендеры, в которых выигрывала конкретная компания.

*Тендер* ***Tender***: `id`, `bet_winner_id` (ссылка на выигравшую ставку)

*Ставка* ***Bet***: `id`, `tender_id` (ссылка на тендер), `company_id` (ссылка на компанию)

*Компания* ***Company***: `id`

```
class Tender extends Model
{
    /**
     * Все ставки
     * @return HasMany
     */
    public function bets()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Bet::class, "tender_id", "id");
    }

    /**
     * Выигранная ставка
     * @return HasOne
     */
    public function winBet()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Bet::class, "id", "bet_winner_id");
    }
}
```

```
class Bet extends Model
{
  /**
   * Тендер
   * @return HasOne
   */
  public function tender()
  {
      return $this->hasOne(Tender::class, "id", "tender_id");
  }

  /**
   * Компания
   * @return HasOne
   */
  public function company()
  {
      return $this->hasOne(Company::class, "id", "company_id");
  }
}
```

```
class Company extends Model
{
  /**
   * Ставки
   * @return HasMany
   */
  public function bets()
  {
      return $this->hasMany(Bet::class, "company_id", "id");
  }
}
```

Я создал такой метод:

```
class Tender extends Model
{
  /**
   * Тендеры, в которых ставила компания
   * @param Builder $query
   * @param int $companyId
   * @param bool|null $isWin только выигрыш
   * @return Builder
   */
  public function scopeCompanyTakePartTenders(Builder $query, int $companyId, ?bool $isWin = null)
  {
      return $query->whereHas("bets", function ($q) use ($companyId, $isWin) {
          $q->where("company_id", "=", $companyId);
          $q->whereHas("tender", function ($q) use ($companyId, $isWin) {
              $q->where("tender.bet_winner_id", "=", "bet.id");
          });
      });
  }
}
```

Тем не менее, он не работает, `count()` возвращает ноль, хотя однозначно по данным должна быть единица:

```
$id = $company->getKey();
$query = Tender::companyTakePartTenders($id)->toSql();
$cnt = Tender::companyTakePartTenders($id)->count(); // <---
dump("$id: $cnt");
dump($query);
```

Дампится такой запрос:

```
select * from "tender" where exists
(select * from "bet" where "tender"."id" = "bet"."tender_id" and "company_id" = ? and exists
  (select * from "tender" where "bet"."tender_id" = "tender"."id" and "tender"."bet_winner_id" = ?
    and "tender"."deleted_at" is null
  )
) and "tender"."deleted_at" is null
```

Я не понимаю, почему такой код:

```
$q->where("tender.bet_winner_id", "=", "bet.id");
```

формирует такой запрос:

```
"tender"."bet_winner_id" = ?
```

Как правильно написать код?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Я не понимаю, почему такой код:
>
> ```
> $q->where("tender.bet_winner_id", "=", "bet.id");
> ```

Потому что builder препарирует входящие значения. Для исправления надо воспользоваться методом

```
$q->whereRaw("tender.bet_winner_id = bet.id");
```